# Creating on demand workflow directly in Production instance

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need a temporary workflow to update records in Production instance. I was thinking to just create one in production directly and run it on records and delete it. Whats the best way to do it, should I just create it in customization area (i.e. Default solution) and then delete it later or create a new solution, add this work flow to that solution and then delete that solution?

Or should I create it in Dev and then move the solution to Test/Production like we normally do?

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice, create it in Dev using a new Hotfix solution - test it against some Dev records. Then export the solution (may be Managed one) & deploy in Test/UAT/Prod.

Once data fix is completed in Prod using our WF, delete the Managed solution (which will delete the WF too).

If you want - you can just deactivate the WF in Prod: Settings - Processes for future usage & to maintain environments in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Never customize in the default solution - unless you're working on a managed solution (of which you have no control in Dev/Test), or are looking for a full list of components in an entity without adding them to your Solution (example - when writing a plugin, you need to know the field names of OOTB fields - I go to Default Solution to get these).

You didn't tell us in the message what your Workflow should be doing, and if it needs to be done in DEV or TEST.

What I would do is build the WF in DEV or test, re-create the situation that needs to be fixed in PROD, and test it in DEV/TEST.  Once you know it will work, you can either push it over as a solution (or as a part of your existing solution), or, you can simply add it to your solution in PROD and then run it as required.  If you need to delete it, great, delete it.  If not, just de-activate it so people don't accidentally run it.

Comment: Its a on demand workflow which basically updates a field on the basis of a lookup value.

Comment: i would still at least run it through test cases to make sure you're not going to bomb production data.  In this scenario, its not (seemingly) as important that the workflow is set through the proper channels (DEV-TEST-PROD), since it is such a small workflow.  But that doesn't mean its not dangerous.  So, thoroughly test your WF in one of your previous environments, and then move it up there however you want once all testing is complete.  The method of getting it into PROD won't be anywhere near as important as the impact it has on your PROD data.